# reloadData not working for UICollectionView in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uicollectionview

So basically i have search method "searchTableList" and after i get the result i want, i want to reload the uicollectionview

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
   // NSLog(@"Text change - %d",isSearching);

    //Remove all objects first.
    [filteredContentList removeAllObjects];

    if([searchText length] != 0) {
        isSearching = YES;
        [self searchTableList];
    }
    else {
        isSearching = NO;
    }

    [self.collectionView reloadData];


}
```

However after "[self.collectionView reloadData]" Nothing happens !

After using this, it crashes all the time !

```
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

What can i do, Thanks alot!!! :D

Error message is:

```
    2014-04-16 18:24:35.684 SampleProject1[59602:60b] the item width must be less that the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values.
2014-04-16 18:24:37.709 SampleProject1[59602:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionView.m:3688
2014-04-16 18:24:37.713 SampleProject1[59602:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert item 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 items in section 0 after the update'
```

**Fixed It:**

Basically i was returning the count of an unused array which always had a lenght of 0 instead of the relevant array !

So i had to change This:

```
if (isSearching) {

    return [searchResult count];

} else {
    return [self.tracks count];
}
```

To:
       if (isSearching) {

```
        return [filteredContentList count];

    } else {
        return [self.tracks count];
    }
```

Then after this i removed all the reloadData jargons and replaced it with:

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Thanks alot guys !!

Comment: If it crashes, what is the error message?

Comment: @MarcMosby just updated the code and the error message :)

Comment: Google your last error message. Only the reason text.

Comment: Is the delegate assigned properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- After writing reloadItemsAtIndexPaths no need of writing again
  reloadData.
- Reload the respective collection View row using main thread.

Code Snippet:

```
[[NSOperationQueue  mainQueue]  addOperationWithBlock:^{

    // Reload the respective collection view row using the main thread.

    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];

}];
```

Comment: What is the crash log ?Is it the same as previous?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341778/uicollectionviewflowlayout-not-invalidating-right-on-orientation-change

Comment: Thanks alot brother ! finally fixed. After going through your solution i found out that i was returning 0 this was because i was using an unused array. How stupid of me :) Thanks alot for the time though !!

Comment: @Pizzy213codes, I can be your sister :). M female :)

Comment: how do we do that in swift 3?

Answer (score 0):

Check for any [collectionView reloadData] commands in your willDisplayCell... method.  I had this in there and it worked once, but when I needed to reloadData again with a new dataset it just wouldn't trigger any more willDisplayCell calls.

It was all on the main thread, that wasn't the problem.  More like an overflow problem.